# Enabling symbol levels using PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, symbology

After a day of unsuccessfully searching, I ask for help -how can I use symbol levels in PyQGIS plugin . Here is my code that display the layer:

```
layer = self.iface.activeLayer()

symbol =QgsLineSymbol.createSimple ({'color':'black', 'width':'0.8', 'line_style':'solid'})    
symbol_l2 = QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayer.create ({'color':'white', 'width':'0.5', 'line_style':'solid'})    
symbol.appendSymbolLayer (symbol_l2)

rendererr = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer (symbol)    
layer.setRenderer(rendererr)
```

In QGIS DESKTOP, you can see the intersection of roads clean without lines,
after executing the following commands :

layer properties -> symbology -> line -> Advanced -> Symbol Levels -> Enable symbol level`

[image: Commands in QGIS desktop:]

[image: Display before of using symbol levels: :]

[image: Display after using symbol levels – that I want to do in my plugin :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right before setting the layer's renderer, you need to use the `QgsFeatureRenderer.setUsingSymbolLevels()` method, in this way:

```
renderer.setUsingSymbolLevels(True)
```

And that's it!

Comment: Although the forum management does not want to do this, I have to say thank you very much !!!!

Comment: Jeje, you're welcome, glad that it helped you. You were very close actually. As a hint, next time you can look for key words in the official QGIS GitHub repo. It might point you to the right direction.

Comment: I don't know what you mean "official QGIS GitHub repo" . Do you can give some example?

Comment: Example: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?q=symbol+levels&unscoped_q=symbol+levels